# How to understand " user programs (called clients or applications) running on remote systems" in X11's The Server−Client Model?

Tags: x11, xorg

I am trying to understand X11's `1.2.2 The Server−Client Model` in the book `XLIB Programming Manual`, There are descriptions:

```
The server acts as an intermediary between user programs (called clients or
applications) running on either the local or remote systems and the
resources of the local system.
```

and the relative Figure as follows:

[image]
I can understand such a situation where the X-server and X-client are in the same linux, for example, the Fedora 24 I am using has `xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.18.3-2.fc24.x86_64` *X-server* and also `xfce4-terminal-0.6.3-9.fc24.x86_64` *x-client*.

But I can not understand `...on remote system` in the above statement.

I can not image there only is `xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.18.3-2.fc24.x86_64` installed in a computer and there is  `xfce4-terminal-0.6.3-9.fc24.x86_64` installed on other several computers without `xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.18.3-2.fc24.x86_64`, or said I don't know how to build a experiment using several computers to understand the above

```
The server acts as an intermediary between user programs (called clients or
applications) running only on remote systems and the resources of the local system.
```

Comment: Here's an experiment for you: run `ssh -X user@host` to some remote machine, and run `xterm` there.  This assumes X is installed and X11 forwarding is not disabled on the remote machine.  The server is the X environment on your local machine.  The client is `xterm` from the remote machine.  You can do that without `ssh`, but the setup is more involved (and a lot less secure).

Comment: I tested it, but I did not see any difference, can you show me the difference? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Difference from what?  The `xterm` is running remotely, it's an example of remote client.

Comment: In my Fedora Linux with X11 forwarding enabled and starting xterm, In my Mac OS's terminal, I run ssh -X abelard@fedora and ssh abelard@fedora, I got the same result, there should have a difference, Or I did something wrong!

Comment: I'm afraid you lost me.  Difference between what?

Comment: I mean the difference between `ssh -X user@host` and `ssh user@host`

Comment: `-X` enables X11 forwarding.  It might not make any difference if it was already enabled in the config files.  You can disable it explicitly, with `-x` instead of `-X`.  After that you won't be able to run `xterm` (on any other X application) on the remote machine.